# Async function not updating view

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I've been experiencing some issues since updating to Angular 9. For example, the following code used to be working fine for me:

```
this.countdownSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
  this.recentAuctions.forEach(a => {
    a.timeLeft = this.auctionService.getTimeLeft(a);
  });
});
```

So, inside this subscription I'm changing the `timeLeft` on the `auction` object. In the HTML I'm displaying that time. However, the change doesn't get reflected in the view unless I call `detectChanges()` on the `ChangeDetectorRef` instance.

Is this expected behavior? Are you supposed to call `detectChanges()` after changing the view in async functions? If not, what could the problem be? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NgZone`.

Run your function inside the `run` function:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

MyFunction() {
    this.countdownSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
        this.zone.run(() => this.recentAuctions.forEach(a => a.timeLeft = this.auctionService.getTimeLeft(a)));
    });
}
```

This will update your view.
More on `NgZone`: https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Answer (score 0):

That's weird how this issue appeared in Angular 9 but there were no issues before.

The only idea I have is to try to update the `a` object and `recentAuctions` array immutably so they get new pointers to where they are located in memory and hopefully will kick in change detection.

Try:

```
this.countdownSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
  this.recentAuctions = this.recentAuctions.map(auction => ({
     ...auction,
     timeLeft: this.auctionService.getTimeLeft(auction),
  }));
});
```

See if that works. The `.map` will transform the array of objects into a new location in memory and the spread operator `...auction` will spread the previous key/values of the object to a new location in memory but `timeLeft` will be overwritten.